# How can I prevent the VMware toolbar from displaying without locking the mouse in the machine with exclusive mode?

Tags: vmware-workstation

When I use VMware workstation, I have the host machine on another monitor and I want to use both, but every time I go to a tab on the guest machine, the toolbar drops down and gets in the way. If I enter exclusive mode manually via edit, the mouse is grabbed and I have to release the mode with ctrl-alt to use the mouse on the host again. Is there a way to just hide the VMware toolbar?

Answer (score 0):

1. While not an optimal answer, you can extend the guest into two monitors and then keep your web browsers, tabbed windows on the 2nd monitor where the VM toolbar doesn't drop down. Then have your host windows on a third monitor and not use the left most monitor at all because of the stupid VMware toolbar. I may switch to another VM environment just to get rid of that stupid bar from coming down.
2. If you're very careful, don't let the mouse touch the top of the monitor window and I have discovered the toolbar doesn't come down. Just remember to never go all the way to the top. (This is very hard after many years of habit and a fast mouse pointer speed setting).